# Writing column as a combination of letter and number in range

Tags: excel, vba

I want to refer to a column in range which is a combination of letter and number. I want to accomplish something like: Range(K & input no. & ":" & Y & output no. ) for referring to K2 and Y8- input no. being 2 and output no. being 8, taken from input box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that problem is your variable name: **input no.** and **output no.**

Modify them to input_no and output_no. It will OK.

Small syntax error. Try this

```
Range("K" & input_no & ":Y" & output_no)
```